# How to show Google Map in a different shape

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to find (without luck so far) any examples of Google Maps that are shown in a shape that is not the standard rectangle.

I know that ultimately the map IS a rectangle, but specifically I'd like examples of how I could show graphics on top of that rectangle to give the illusion that the map borders are a different shape.

To explain further what I mean, imagine a page with a black background with a standard Google Map (rectangle) in the top left.  Now imagine placing a DIV over the bottom half of the map, where this DIV contains half a black circle and a transparent background.  The purpose would be to give the illusion that the map has a curved bottom edge.

I'd then want to do something similar with the remaining 3 sides so that the map no longer appears like it's in a rectangle.

To explain further still, I'm going to be given a web page template which will have a shape - not a rectangle - into which I'm expected to put a Google Map...

Importantly, I'd still need to be able to 'grab' the map with the mouse and move it about within its 'new shape'.

Any advice would be appreciated - thanks.

Comment: same problem here - anyone with solutions pls?